# Firefox address bar doesn't autocomplete

Tags: 10.10, firefox, troubleshooting

When I start computer; or resume from standby; for few minutes firefox address bar does not offer autocomplete. After few minutes, every works normally.

ubuntu maverick
firefox 3.6.12 that came with ubuntu, updated through apt-get
laptop thinkpad t60p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing what [this page](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/firefox/firefox-address-bar-lag-solution/) suggests. Also try [this](http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2008/08/getting-around-slow-firefox3-urladdress.html) or [this](http://www.patmullin.com/weblog/2008/08/21/firefox-3-url-bar-is-killing-me/) (seems to be identical).

It's a good idea to backup your Firefox settings before you do something like that - so run this: `cp -a ~/.mozilla ~/mozilla_bak`. If something goes wrong, you can always fix it by running `mv ~/.mozilla ~/mozilla_broken && cp -a ~/mozilla_bak ~/.mozilla`

Comment: thanks, did what you suggested and http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-tipspeed-up-firefox-by-compacting-sqlite-databases; and tried suspend resume again; works like charm (1 of these or all 3 helped :D)

Answer (score 0):

The bar takes a while to load, it's all based on the slow file based sql. The more history, bookmarks and other items you have, the longer it takes to load. Try clearing the browser history and see if that helps.

There's also an outstanding bug where the bar gets confused and doesn't ever show the suggestions, but that doesn't sound like what you're describing.

Comment: hmmm, your logic is sound; is there any  option other then clearing history? if it helps,  i have same history and bookmarks on win7; and it doesn't show this problem

Comment: Firefox is fundamentally a windows project, we often don't get fair dealing when it comes to making firefox run awesome on Linux.